# Angularjs nested elements directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build 2 elements: `<accordion>` and `<accordion-group-active>`.

```
.directive('accordion', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div class=\"accordion\" ng-transclude>  \
                   </div>"
    }
})
```

and

```
.directive('accordion-active-group', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div class=\"title\" > \
                     <i class=\"dropdown icon\"></i> \
                     {{heading}} \
                   </div>"
    }
})
```

Why i'm getting:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <accordion-active-group class="ng-scope">test</accordion-active-group>
    <accordion-active-group class="ng-scope">test2</accordion-active-group>
    <accordion-active-group class="ng-scope">test3</accordion-active-group>
</div>
```

Instead:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div> ... </div>
    <div> ... </div>
    <div> ... </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Camel case in js hyphenated in HTML

Comment: Can you post your original HTML?

Comment: also combine single/double quotes so you do not need to escape them (for better readability) `template: '<div class="title">' + ...`

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Use camelCase in your javascript, not hyphens. So .directive('accordion-active-group') should be .directive('accordionActiveGroup')
2. You're missing an ng-transclude directive in the template of your 2nd directive. Angular won't know where to place your transcluded content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 1. Fixed. 2. Added `ng-transclude` to the `"<div class=\"title\" > \` but the same`

Answer (score -1):

```
/*activity*/
actApp.directive('graph3p', ['composite', 'component', function (composite, component) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: "div class='graph3p' ng-transclude></div>",

    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        //Add the element to the main components collection
        $scope.components.push($element);
        $element.html($scope.asset);
        var _svgObj = $element[0].getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
        var resolvedText;
        var actDataArr= [];

        for(var i = 0; i <= 19; i++){
            resolvedText = composite.resolve($scope, "data["+i+"]");
            actDataArr = resolvedText.split(",")
            $attrs.cx = actDataArr[0]
            $attrs.cy = actDataArr[1]

            var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'circle');

            circle.setAttribute('id',"cir" + i);
            circle.setAttribute('cx',$attrs.cx);
            circle.setAttribute('cy',$attrs.cy);
            circle.setAttribute('r',2);
            circle.setAttribute('fill','#FF0000');
            circle.setAttribute('stroke','#FF0000');
            circle.setAttribute('stroke-width',0.8);
            circle.setAttribute('stroke-miterlimit',10);
            _svgObj.appendChild(circle);
        }
        component.position($scope, $element, $attrs);
        component.size($scope, $element, $attrs);
    }
}
}]);
```

Comment: Provide some explanation instead of plain code, hardly related to OP's one.